# Visual Keying not Properly Recording IK When Baking Animation

Tags: animation, keyframes, baking, constraints, inverse-kinematics

While animating something recently, I've come across something I've never seen before. I had just finished the [following animation](https://gyazo.com/070e343d30d3a0e2041e492f93797d59), and since I had used the spring bones plugin to simulate the hat physics, I planned on baking the entire animation with visual keying. After doing so, the animation looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/4eae09fd5da1d592bbd7962b3bf02d59) (notice how the IK was not baked properly). Any ideas why this is the case? Just to clarify, yes every bone was baked, all are keyframed in the action, the only differences between the first and second gif are that it was baked and that the constraints are no longer active on the latter, no other changes.

[image: baking settings]

here is the blender file containing the animation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad3nqj24xmeda4b/MonsterIdle.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please do not use external links to describe a question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your root bone has (keyframed) non-uniform scale-- scale that is different in its three axes.  Non-uniform scale can often create situations where a visual transform is not quite possible, and definitely not easy to calculate, and apparently, Blender's visual transforms do not handle it properly.  (Its IK constraints don't handle it properly either, and that is probably an unsolvable situation, so you don't want IK chain bones to be inheriting non-uniform scale anyways.)

Once you clear the scale on Root and delete its scale keyframes, the bake comes out exactly the same as this modified animation.  However, if you've built your animation around Root's scale, it might not be exactly what you want.  You may have to edit your animation slightly.

Comment: alright then, didn't realize this was an issue and I'm surprised I haven't run into this issue before, thanks for letting me know!